# How to Add ComputeBudget into Versioned Transaction?

Tags: versionedtransactions, compute-budget

I want to Modify the compute unit for Versioned Transactions but there are some issue with that.

Before i Have used it for legacy transaction
but now when i want to add new compute unit size to TransactionV0
it doesn't do that like before.

General Snippet codes for addComputeUnit, Create and Send v0 transaction:

```
const modifyComputeUnits = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit({
    units: 1000000   });

const addPriorityFee = ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice({
    microLamports: 1   });

const instruction = [
         await program.methods.breedBee(false)
           .accounts({list of accounts})
           .signers([ list of signers])
           .instruction()
         ]

const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: staging_wallet.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
      instructions: instruction
    }).compileToV0Message([lookupTable]);


const transactionV0 = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);

transactionV0.add(modifyComputeUnits); transactionV0.add(addPriorityFee);
```

❌ Property 'add' does not exist on type 'VersionedTransaction'.

---

So I changed .instruction() to .transaction() and then wanted to add modifyComputeUnits by this way:

```
const instruction = await program.methods.breedBee(false)
           .accounts({list of accounts})
           .signers([ list of signers])
           .transaction()

           
instruction.add(modifyComputeUnits)
instruction.add(addPriorityFee)
instruction.recentBlockhash = blockhash
instruction.feePayer = staging_wallet.publicKey
```

with this approach I faced with another error while passing instruction into TransactionMessage:

```
const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: staging_wallet.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
      instructions: instruction
    }).compileToV0Message([lookupTable]);
```

❌ the error:

TypeError: instructions is not iterable

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'header')

so it can't compile TransactionMessage.

Answer (score 2):

**Finally I could solve the issue by this way;**

```
const instruction = await program.methods.breedBee(false)
           .accounts({list of accounts})
           .signers([ list of signers])
           .transaction()

           
instruction.add(modifyComputeUnits)
instruction.add(addPriorityFee)
instruction.recentBlockhash = blockhash
instruction.feePayer = staging_wallet.publicKey
```

**and use the instruction in TransactionMessage by this format;**

```
const messageV0 = new TransactionMessage({
      payerKey: staging_wallet.publicKey,
      recentBlockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
      instructions: instruction.instructions
    }).compileToV0Message([lookupTable]);

const transactionV0 = new VersionedTransaction(messageV0);
transactionV0.sign([ signers ]);

const txid = await connection.sendTransaction(transactionV0, { maxRetries: 5 });

const confirmation = await connection.confirmTransaction({
    signature: txid,
    blockhash: latestBlockhash.blockhash,
    lastValidBlockHeight: latestBlockhash.lastValidBlockHeight
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can this code:

```
    const ix_1 = solana.ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitLimit(
    {
        units: 300_000
    }
);
const ix_2 = solana.ComputeBudgetProgram.setComputeUnitPrice(
    {
        microLamports: 50_000
    }
);

        const block = await connection.getLatestBlockhash();
    const txMsg = new solana.TransactionMessage(
        {
            payerKey: wallet.publicKey,
            recentBlockhash: block.blockhash,
            instructions: [
                ix_1,
                ix_2
            ]
        }
    ).compileToV0Message();
    const tx = new solana.VersionedTransaction(txMsg);
```